# ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series - Windows 8 - 1920x1200 resolution

Tags: windows-8, resolution, ati-mobility-radeon

I bought new monitor Samsung SyncMaster S24B420 (1920x1200 60Hz native resolution) and connected via a VGA/DB15 cable. I have problem that in Windwos 8 I can set only 1600x1200 as maximal resolution.

I tried install official monitor drivers, but I think that problem is in ATI driver because when I show "List All Modes" in "Advanced setting" for screen resolution I see that maximal is 1600x1200

But I can't find ATI driver, because they don't release W8 drivers they recommend use Microsft native driver "ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1)"

My HW Lenovo R500 type 2732-32G

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The generic drivers are your only choice with the graphic you have.

Comment: Questing is how I can set 1920x1200 resolution .. Graphic card can set 2048 x 1536 resolution for VGA output

Comment: Have you tried installing the legacy AMD drivers for Win8? http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/catalystlegacywin8.aspx

Comment: @Lennart Yes I tried it, there is packed same generic driver for W8 "Display Driver (WDDM 1.1)"

Comment: True, but it includes the Catalyst Control Center with which you can add HD resolutions.

Comment: @Lennart I installed it once again but there I can set only 1600x1200 as maximum resolution (in Desktop Managment tab -> Desktop properties) .... in My VGA displays -> Properties (VGA display) I uncheck "Use Extended Display Identification data" and set 1920x1200 60Hz as maximal resolution, but it haven't any effect :(

Comment: Is there a page with "HDTV Support"? I currently can't replicate it, since I don't have a VGA monitor.

Comment: @Lennart I cant find this page :(

Comment: Weird, getting the latest legacy Catalyst driver for the HD series always worked for me on all 7 to 8.1 windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Thinkvantage System Update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&DocID=HT072045#)  It have found problem drivers for me in the past.

Comment: I tried it but it only offering download "Lenovo Power Management Driver" and "ThinkVantage Active Protection System" ... nothing what I need :(

Answer (score -1):

I had struggled with this same resolution problem in Windows 7 and my solution may work for you if your system has similar ports.

Both my monitor, FHD2400, and video card, ATI FireGL v3600, supported 1920x1200 but that option did not show on the selection menu. The monitor had been detected by Windows as a generic and not recognized by the model. I had the monitor connected to the card with a VGA connection thru a KVM with a VGA to DVI connector at the video card.

I switched to a DVI cable directly from the card to the monitor and upon reboot windows recognized the monitor and automatically selected the 1920x1200 resolution.